# Open and play video in VLC or MPC using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I would like to ask if anybody know how it is possible to open video in VLC or MPC player in Guide application using PushButton in Matlab.

I tried this simple command "open('1.avi)", but it makes error: "Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.".

Comment: Maybe try `winopen`?

Comment: @Adiel Is there equivalent command for Linux and OSX users?

Comment: Great! Its exactly what I´ve looked for! Thank you

Comment: @Crowley for mac there is `macopen` : http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25080-macopen

Comment: @Adiel Can you turn your comments into an answer?

Comment: @Crowley I have no time or patience for doing it properly right now... You can gladly do it with a credit, and grab the reputations :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the [`system`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html?refresh=true) command to launch an external application such as VLC.

If you're on Windows it would be something like:

```
system('"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\VLC.exe" 1.avi')
```

For more information and information on other operating systems, checkout the VLC command line documentation [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Command_line/) and [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/)

Comment: @Adiel I would think so too but that depends on the user's PATH

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered, you can open it in another program like VLC or MPC using functions such as winopen(), macopen(), or system(). Alternatively, you could embed an instance of VLC directly into your GUI using an ActiveX controller.